# How to send Azure Test Plan execution results in azure devops release email option

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After execution of Azure Pipeline and Azure releases. I send the notification via release send mail option
[image]

I want to share the manual test execution results of Azure test plans in this release email. Please let me know the way. Or any other option to share the test execution results (azure test plans)

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way to update the notification/email template.

Besides, there is a related [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customize-vsts-email-templates.html) about it, you can up vote there and monitor status of it.

As a workaround, you could try to use some 3rd-party extension such as [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) or [SendGrid Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.sendgrid-email) task, and add it to the release pipeline, through this task you can customize the email.

[image]

> - Email  Body : Contents of the email you want to send.To send HTML body add    the HTML here and set the Send as HTML checkbox. (Optional)